# Mostrar fecha a determinados días con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero poder seleccionar una fecha en`SOAT_DESDE` con el calendario`tcal` y que automáticamente en `SOAT_HASTA` me muestre la fecha un año después. El código que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente:

**SCRIPT**

```
var fecha1 = document.getElementById("SOAT_DESDE");
var fecha2 = document.getElementById("SOAT_HASTA");

function calcular(){
    var hoy = new Date();
    var dias = parseInt(364);
    var calculado = new Date();
    calculado.setDate(hoy.getDate() + dias);
    fecha2.innerText = calculado.getFullYear() + '/' +
(calculado.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + calculado.getDate();
```

**HTML**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script>

<td>
    Desde:
    <input type="text" name="SOAT_DESDE" id="SOAT_DESDE" class="tcal"/>
    Hasta:
    <input type="text" name="SOAT_HASTA" id="SOAT_HASTA" class="tcal"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Podrias darme el CDN de tus archivos? para poder ayudarte

Comment: Ya lo puse en la pregunta

Comment: Los archvios tcal.css y tcal.js no estan..

Comment: Son necesarios? esa simplemente son una librerías para llamar el calendario, te comento que también tengo otros campos en los que necesito llamar la fecha normal.

Answer (score 1):

He puesto por defecto la fecha de hoy en tu input `SOAT_DESDE` para hacerlo más rápido (puedes cambiar la fecha si deseas para probarlo).

El código quedaría así:

```js
function calcular() {
  // Inputs
  var fecha1 = document.getElementById("SOAT_DESDE");
  var fecha2 = document.getElementById("SOAT_HASTA");

  // Fechas
  var calculado = new Date(fecha1.value);
  calculado.setDate(calculado.getDate() + 365);

  fecha2.value = 
    calculado.getFullYear() + '/' +
    (calculado.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + 
    calculado.getDate();
}
```

```html
Desde:
<input type="text" name="SOAT_DESDE" id="SOAT_DESDE" class="tcal" value="2018/03/23"/>
Hasta:
<input type="text" name="SOAT_HASTA" id="SOAT_HASTA" class="tcal"/>
<button id="btnCalcular" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
```

Ten en cuenta que:

- He agregado un botón para realizar el cálculo.
- No es necesario usar `parseInt` en algo que de por sí ya es un entero: `364`, de hecho, lo estoy pasando directamente al cálculo.
- No necesitas dos fechas para realizar el cálculo. Simplemente usas `setDate()` para aumentar los días en la misma fecha.
- Ya que estás trabajando con `input`s, lo correcto sería usar `fecha2.value` en vez de `fecha2.innerText`.

Comment: Master me surgio una duda comparando tu solución y la mía.. si te fijas, al día también tuve que sumarle un 1, sin embargo tú no lo haces. En que se diferencia?

Comment: Hola @PauloUrbanoRivera, uhmmm, no estoy seguro: `new Date('2018/03/01').getDate()` da como resultado `1`. En cambio a `new Date('2018/03/01').getDate()` si hay que hacerle un `+1` ya que retorna `2`

Comment: Cosas de programación jaajaj.. Excelente semana colega!

Answer (score 0):

Complementando la respuesta del colega César (ya que en tu pregunta indicas que deseas que se haga automáticamente), te adjunto mi solución:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Desde:
    <input type="date" name="SOAT_DESDE" id="SOAT_DESDE" />
    Hasta:
    <input type="date" name="SOAT_HASTA" id="SOAT_HASTA" />
  </body>
  <script>
      $('#SOAT_DESDE').on('change', function(){
    var myDate = new Date($(this).val());
    var customDate = document.getElementById("SOAT_HASTA");
    var format = (myDate.getFullYear() + 1) + '-' + ('0' + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)) + '-' + ('0' + (myDate.getDate() + 1)).slice(-2);
    $('#SOAT_HASTA').val(format); 
  })
    </script>
</html>
```

**A los meses y días se les suma (+1) porque ambos parten de base cero**

Saludos!